Qtextcursorが引数として使えないとのエラーが表示されます
質問内容
Qtextcursorが引数として使えないとのエラーが表示されます。matplotlob,python,pyqtに精通している方、ご教授お願いします。
以下はコードと, エラーメッセージ
my code
# core GUI libraries
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QFileDialog
#from PyQtCore import QRunnable, QThreadPool, pyqtSlot


# from threading import Thread

import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString

# change matplotlib settings to make plots look nicer
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 20
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 20
plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 3
plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.width'] = 3
plt.rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 3
plt.rcParams['ytick.minor.width'] = 3
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.width'] = 3
plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = True


class Worker(QtCore.QRunnable):
    """Class to start a new worker thread for background tasks.

    Call this thread inside a main GUI function by:
    worker = Worker(self.function_to_execute)  # , pass other args here,...,)
    self.threadpool.start(worker)
    where self.function_to_execute is the function to run and its args
    """
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        """This allows the Worker class to take any function as an
        argument, along with args, and run it in a separate thread."""
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        """Take a function and its args which were passed to the Worker
        class and execute it in a new thread."""
        self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  


class App(QMainWindow):
    """Class which creates the main window of the application."""

    # load Qt designer XML .ui GUI file
    Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType('ui.ui')

    def __init__(self):

        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.ui = App.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # initialize multithreading
        self.threadpool = QtCore.QThreadPool()

        # assign functions to top menu items
        # example: self.ui.menu_item_name.triggered.connect(self.function_name)
        self.ui.actionShowfiledir.triggered.connect(self.show_directory)
        self.ui.actionChangefiledir.triggered.connect(self.set_directory)
        self.ui.actionQuit.triggered.connect(self.quitapp)

        # assign actions to GUI buttons
        # example: self.ui.BUTTON_NAME.clicked.connect(self.FUNCTION_NAME)
        self.ui.fit_model.clicked.connect(self.fit_model_in_new_thread)
        
        self.ui.plot_df_surf.clicked.connect(self.plot_df_surf)
        self.ui.plot_dd_surf.clicked.connect(self.plot_dd_surf)
        self.ui.plot_sol_surf.clicked.connect(self.plot_sol_surf)
        self.ui.export_results.clicked.connect(self.export_results)
        
        # assign actions to checkboxes
        # example: self.ui.CHECKBOX.stateChanged.connect(self.FUNCTION_NAME)
        
        # set default data folder and create it if it doesn't exist
        self.filedir = os.getcwd()+'\\QCMD_model_results'
        if not os.path.exists(self.filedir):
            os.makedirs(self.filedir)


# %% ----------- system control functions ------------------------------

    # file I/O utilities ---------------------------------------------------

    def export_results(self):
        """Save modeling results to file."""
        filename = 'QCMD_results'
        filepath = self.filedir + '\\' + filename + '.csv'
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(self.results.items()))
        df.to_csv(filepath)
        self.ui.outbox.append('\nFile saved to ' + filepath)


    def set_directory(self):
        """Set the directory for saving files."""
        self.filedir = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
                self, 'Select a directory for storing data'))
        self.ui.outbox.append('\nFile directory is set to ' + self.filedir)


    def show_directory(self):
        """Show the file directory in the output box."""
        self.ui.outbox.append('\nFile directory is set to ' + self.filedir)


    def fit_model_in_new_thread(self):
        """Run Kelvin-Voigt model in new thread."""
        worker = Worker(self.fit_model)  # pass other args here
        self.threadpool.start(worker)


    def get_ui_inputs(self):
        """Get a dictionary of inputs from the UI."""
        uidict = {
                'f0': float(self.ui.f0.currentText())*1e6,
                'n': int(self.ui.n.currentText()),
                'rho': float(self.ui.film_density.value()),
                'h': float(self.ui.film_thickness.value())*1e-9,
                'medium': str(self.ui.medium.currentText()),
                'df_exp': float(self.ui.df_exp.value()),
                'dd_exp': float(self.ui.dd_exp.value()),
                'mu_low': int(self.ui.mu_exp_low.value()),
                'mu_high': int(self.ui.mu_exp_high.value()),
                'eta_low': int(self.ui.eta_exp_low.value()),
                'eta_high': int(self.ui.eta_exp_high.value())}
        return uidict


    def mu_eta_mesh(self, uidict):
        """Create mesh of mu and eta valuses using inputs on UI."""
        # get 2D 1mesh grid points of log mu and eta values
        step_num=50
        mu_mesh, eta_mesh = np.meshgrid(
                np.linspace(uidict['mu_low'], uidict['mu_high'],
                            step_num).astype(float),
                np.linspace(uidict['eta_low'], uidict['eta_high'],
                            step_num).astype(float))
        #get mesh of mu and eta values and corresponding DF and DD values        
        df_surf, dd_surf = self.kelvin_voigt(
                             10**mu_mesh,
                             10**eta_mesh,
                             rho_f=uidict['rho'],
                             h_f=uidict['h'],
                             n=uidict['n'],
                             f0=uidict['f0'],
                             medium=uidict['medium'])
        return mu_mesh, eta_mesh, df_surf, dd_surf          


    def fit_model(self):
        """Run modeling of the QCM-D dtaa using inputs from UI. """
        self.ui.fit_model.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.outbox.append('------------------------------------------')
        self.ui.outbox.append('Fitting model...')
        # get dictionary of input values from UI
        uidict = self.get_ui_inputs()
        self.results = uidict.copy()
        self.contours = {}
        
        # get grid of possible mu, eta, df, and dd values
        mu_mesh, eta_mesh, df_surf, dd_surf = self.mu_eta_mesh(uidict)
        # plot delta F heatmap
        plt.ioff()
        df_cont_plot = plt.contour(
                mu_mesh, eta_mesh, df_surf, uidict['df_exp'])
        # plot delta D heatmap
        dd_cont_plot = plt.contour(
                mu_mesh, eta_mesh, dd_surf, uidict['dd_exp'])
        
        # extract contours which correspond to experimental values
        df_cont = self.get_contour(df_cont_plot)
        dd_cont = self.get_contour(dd_cont_plot)
        # find intersection of solutions
        intersection_list = np.array(
                self.find_intersections(df_cont, dd_cont))
        plt.cla()
        # if there are any solutions, select the 0th-order solution
        if len(intersection_list) > 0:
            sol = sorted(intersection_list, key = lambda i: float(i[1]))[-1]
            
            # get calculated mu and eta values, along with G' and G'' 
            mu, eta, = 10**sol[0], 10**sol[1]
            Gp, Gdp = mu, 2*np.pi*uidict['f0']*eta
            # get fitted df and dd values
            df_fit, dd_fit = self.kelvin_voigt(mu, eta,
                                               rho_f=uidict['rho'],
                                               h_f=uidict['h'],
                                               n=uidict['n'],
                                               f0=uidict['f0'],
                                               medium=uidict['medium'])
            # get penetration depth
            pen_dep = self.get_penetration_depth(uidict['f0'], eta,
                                                 uidict['rho'])
            
            self.results.update({'df_fit': df_fit, 'dd_fit': dd_fit,
                                 'mu': mu, 'eta': eta,
                                 'penetration_depth': pen_dep,
                                 "G'": Gp, "G''": Gdp})
            self.contours.update({'df_exp': uidict['df_exp'],
                                  'dd_exp': uidict['dd_exp'],
                                  'mu_mesh': mu_mesh, 'eta_mesh': eta_mesh,
                                  'df_surf': df_surf, 'dd_surf': dd_surf,
                                  'df_cont': df_cont, 'dd_cont': dd_cont,
                                  'sol': sol})

            self.ui.outbox.append(
                    'Found '+str(len(intersection_list))+' solutions.')
            self.ui.outbox.append('First-order solution:')
            self.ui.plot_sol_surf.setDisabled(False)
            self.ui.plot_df_surf.setDisabled(False)
            self.ui.plot_dd_surf.setDisabled(False)
            self.ui.export_results.setDisabled(False)
            for key in self.results:
                self.ui.outbox.append(str(key)+': '+str(self.results[key]))

        else:
            self.ui.outbox.append(
                    '\n\nNo solutions exist with these parameters.')
            self.ui.plot_sol_surf.setDisabled(True)
            self.ui.plot_df_surf.setDisabled(True)
            self.ui.plot_dd_surf.setDisabled(True)
            self.ui.export_results.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.fit_model.setDisabled(False)
        self.ui.outbox.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)


    def plot_df_surf(self):
        """Plot delta F surface."""
        plt.cla()
        fig_df = plt.figure(5)
        plt.ion()
        plt.contour(self.contours['mu_mesh'], self.contours['eta_mesh'],
                    self.contours['df_surf'], self.contours['df_exp'])
        plt.contourf(self.contours['mu_mesh'], self.contours['eta_mesh'],
                     self.contours['df_surf'], 50, cmap='rainbow')
        self.plot_setup(title='Δf (Hz/cm^2)',
                   labels=['Log (μ) (Pa)', 'Log (η) (Pa s)'], colorbar=True)
        plt.tight_layout()
        fig_df.canvas.set_window_title('Δf surface')
        fig_df.show()


    def plot_dd_surf(self):
        """Plot delta D surface."""
        plt.cla()
        fig_dd = plt.figure(2)
        plt.ion()
        plt.contour(self.contours['mu_mesh'], self.contours['eta_mesh'],
                    self.contours['dd_surf'], self.contours['dd_exp'])
        plt.contourf(self.contours['mu_mesh'], self.contours['eta_mesh'],
                     self.contours['dd_surf'], 50, cmap='rainbow')
        self.plot_setup(title='ΔD (x 10^-6)',
                   labels=['Log (μ) (Pa)', 'Log (η) (Pa s)'], colorbar=True)
        plt.tight_layout()
        fig_dd.canvas.set_window_title('ΔD surface')
        fig_dd.show()


    def plot_sol_surf(self):
        """Plot solution surface."""
        plt.cla()
        fig_df = plt.figure(3)
        plt.ion()
        plt.scatter(self.contours['sol'][0],
                    self.contours['sol'][1], marker='x',
                    s=300, c='k', label='solution')
        # plot contour intersection
        plt.scatter(self.contours['df_cont'][:, 0],
                    self.contours['df_cont'][:, 1], s=1, c='b', label='df')
        plt.scatter(self.contours['dd_cont'][:, 0],
                    self.contours['dd_cont'][:, 1], s=1, c='r', label='dd')
        self.plot_setup(title='Solution',
                   labels=['Log (μ) (Pa)', 'Log (η) (Pa s)'], legend=True)
        plt.tight_layout()
        fig_df.canvas.set_window_title('Solution')
        fig_df.show()


    def plot_setup(self, labels=['X', 'Y'], fsize=20, setlimits=False,
                   title=None, legend=False, colorbar=False,
                   limits=[0,1,0,1], save=False, filename='plot.jpg'):
        """Creates a custom plot configuration to make graphs look nice.
        This can be called with matplotlib for setting axes labels,
        titles, axes ranges, and the font size of plot labels.
        This should be called between plt.plot() and plt.show() commands."""
        plt.xlabel(str(labels[0]), fontsize=fsize)
        plt.ylabel(str(labels[1]), fontsize=fsize)
        fig = plt.gcf()
        fig.set_size_inches(6, 4)
        if title:
            plt.title(title, fontsize=fsize)
        if legend:
            plt.legend(fontsize=fsize-4)
        if setlimits:
            plt.xlim((limits[0], limits[1]))
            plt.ylim((limits[2], limits[3]))
        if colorbar:
            plt.colorbar()
        if save:
            fig.savefig(filename, dpi=120, bbox_inches='tight')
            plt.tight_layout()


    def kelvin_voigt(self, mu_f, eta_f, rho_f=1e3, h_f=1e-6, n=1, f0=5e6,
                    medium='air'):
        """ 
        The Kelvin-Voigt model comes from eqns (15) in the paper by 
        Voinova: Vionova, M.V., Rodahl, M., Jonson, M. and Kasemo, B., 1999.
        Viscoelastic acoustic response of layered polymer films at fluid-solid
        interfaces: continuum mechanics approach. Physica Scripta, 59(5), p.391.
        Reference: https://github.com/88tpm/QCMD/blob/master
        /Mass-specific%20activity/Internal%20functions/voigt_rel.m.
        
        This function solves for Delta f and Delta d of thin adlayer on QCM.
        It differs from voigt because it calculates relative to an
        unloaded resonator.
        Inputs
            mu_f = shear modulus of film in Pa
            eta_f = shear viscosity of film in Pa s
            rho_f = density of film in kg m-3
            h_f = thickness of film in m
            n = crystal harmonic number
            f0 = fundamental resonant frequency of crystal in Hz      
        Output
            deltaf = frequency change of resonator
            deltad =  dissipation change of resonator
        """
        # define properties of QCM crystal
        w = 2*np.pi*f0*n  # angular frequency
        mu_q = 2.947e10  # shear modulus of AT-cut quatz in Pa
        rho_q = 2648  # density of quartz (kg/m^3)
        h_q = np.sqrt(mu_q/rho_q)/(2*f0)  # thickness of quartz
        # define properties of medium
        if medium == 'air':
            rho_b = 1.1839  # density of bulk air (25 C) in kg/m^3
            eta_b = 18.6e-6  # viscosity of bulk air (25 C) in Pa s
        if medium == 'water':
            rho_b = 1000  # density of bulk water in kg/m^3
            eta_b = 8.9e-4  # viscosity of bulk water in Pa s
        # define equations from the Kelvin-Voigt model in publication
        # eqn 14
        kappa_f = eta_f-(1j*mu_f/w)
        # eqn 13
        x_f = np.sqrt(-rho_f*np.square(w)/(mu_f + 1j*w*eta_f))
        x_b = np.sqrt(1j*rho_b*w/eta_b)
        # eqn 11 after simplification with h1 = h2 and h3 = infinity
        A = (kappa_f*x_f+eta_b*x_b)/(kappa_f*x_f-eta_b*x_b)
        # eqn 16
        beta = kappa_f*x_f*(1-A*np.exp(2*x_f*h_f))/(1+A*np.exp(2*x_f*h_f))
        beta0 = kappa_f*x_f*(1-A)/(1+A)
        # eqn 15
        df = np.imag((beta-beta0)/(2*np.pi*rho_q*h_q))
        dd = -np.real((beta-beta0)/(np.pi*f0*n*rho_q*h_q))*1e6
        return df, dd


    def get_contour(self, cont_plot):
        """Get ordered pairs of contour lines from a contour plot.
        Input should be defined as:
        cont_plot = plt.contour(x_mesh, y_mesh, z_surf, contour_value)"""
        # extract contour paths from plot
        paths = [path.vertices for path in cont_plot.collections[0].get_paths()]
        if paths:
            # stack all contour paths in a single 2D array
            return np.vstack(paths)
        else:
            return []


    def find_intersections(self, op_list1, op_list2):
        """Find all intersections between two curves. Curves are defined by lists
        of ordered pairs (x, y).
        Returns an empty list if no intersections are found."""
        intersections = []
        # check if both curves contain more than 1 point:
        if len(op_list1) > 1 and len(op_list2) > 1:
            # loop over each pair of line segments
            for i1 in range(len(op_list1)-1):
                for i2 in range(len(op_list2)-1):
                    # create segment from the first set of points
                    seg1 = LineString([(op_list1[i1][0], op_list1[i1][1]),
                                    (op_list1[i1+1][0], op_list1[i1+1][1])])
                    # create segment from the second set of points
                    seg2 = LineString([(op_list2[i2][0], op_list2[i2][1]),
                                    (op_list2[i2+1][0], op_list2[i2+1][1])])
                    # check if segment from set-1 intersects segment from set-2
                    if seg1.intersects(seg2):
                        avg_x = np.mean([op_list1[i1][0], op_list1[i1+1][0],
                                        op_list2[i2][0], op_list2[i2+1][0]])
                        avg_y = np.mean([op_list1[i1][1], op_list1[i1+1][1],
                                        op_list2[i2][1], op_list2[i2+1][1]])
                        intersections.append([avg_x, avg_y])
        return intersections


    def get_penetration_depth(self, freq, eta, rho):
        """Calculate penetration depth of acoustic wave using the QCM
        resonant requency (freq), adlayer visacosity (eta), and adlayer
        density (rho)."""
        return np.sqrt(eta / (np.pi * freq * rho))


    def quitapp(self):
        """Quit the application."""
        self.deleteLater()
        # self.timer.stop()  # stop timer
        # close app window
        self.close()  
        # kill python kernel
        sys.exit()  



# %% -------------------------- run application ----------------------------


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()

    window = App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

error message
C:\Users\vlrgx\OneDrive\デスクトップ\python_lesson>python app.py
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QTextCursor'
(Make sure 'QTextCursor' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vlrgx\OneDrive\デスクトップ\python_lesson\app.py", line 92, in run
    self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vlrgx\OneDrive\デスクトップ\python_lesson\app.py", line 228, in fit_model
    df_cont_plot = plt.contour(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlrgx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2939, in contour
    __ret = gca().contour(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlrgx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1478, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlrgx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 6520, in contour
    contours = mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlrgx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 858, in __init__
    kwargs = self._process_args(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlrgx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 1523, in _process_args
    x, y, z = self._contour_args(args, kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vlrgx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 1574, in _contour_args
    self._process_contour_level_args(args, z.dtype)
  File "C:\Users\vlrgx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 1237, in _process_contour_level_args
    if len(self.levels) > 1 and np.min(np.diff(self.levels)) <= 0.0:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: len() of unsized object

